# How to get EPSG with OGRinfo?

Tags: ogr, epsg

Is it possible to get the EPSG code of a shapefile with `ogrinfo`? 
I know I can get layers SRS WKT with `ogrinfo -so -al stands1.shp`, but I am looking for the EPSG code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the EPSG code only if the software has written it into the WKT definition of the .prj file.

Using `gdalsrsinfo` on the .prj file also does not offer the information you want. Mabe because there are some EPSG codes that have the same proj definition, but different names.

Answer (score 0):

[Mike Toews](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1872/mike-toews) has a good example that can do this using the OGR python bindings on overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807867/1738472).

It centers around

```
osr.SpatialReference(srsWkt).AutoIdentifyEPSG()
```